# pop out animation of UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am learning swift, I was successfully able to do popup animation of an `UIView` as below code but now i want to do reverse of it. i.e the way the `UIView` was animated should go back on a button click, Like the view is shrinking and then disappears.

```
popupView.isHidden = false
popupInnerView.isHidden = false
popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.popupView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.popupInnerView.transform = .identity
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: put popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0) inside the animation block

Comment: UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
            self.popupInnerView.transform = .identity
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.isHidden = true
            self.popupInnerView.isHidden = true
        })

I tried this way but not working.

Answer (score 11):

Check if this one works for you. I have bound the showing and hiding of popup to buttons but you can bind them to anything.

[image: Popup showing and hiding]

For this to work

- Drag and drop a **uiview**(your popup) into **dock** of view controller (see picture) [image: Popup inside dock]
- **Make outlet** of your uiview(popup) in your view controller. I am calling it popupView

For **showing** popup with Animation use the code

```
 @IBAction func btnShowPopupTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

 popupView.center = view.center
 popupView.alpha = 1
 popupView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 1.2)

 self.view.addSubview(popupView)
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [],  animations: {
 //use if you want to darken the background
   //self.viewDim.alpha = 0.8
   //go back to original form
   self.popupView.transform = .identity
 })

}
```

And for **hiding** the popup

```
@IBAction func btnHideMeTapped(_ sender: Any) {

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
 //use if you wish to darken the background
   //self.viewDim.alpha = 0
   self.popupView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)

 }) { (success) in
   self.popupView.removeFromSuperview()

 }



}
```

Note: If you want to **darken the background** as in gif.

- Drag and drop a uiview into your view heirarchy (view dim). see the pic[image: view Dim]
- pin to 0, 0 , 0 ,0 to the main view
- set its background color to black
- set is alpha to 0
- uncomment the line (self.viewDim.alpha = 0.8) in "btnShowPopupTapped" Action
- uncomment the line (self.viewDim.alpha = 0) in "btnHideMeTapped" Action

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try This

For Zoom in

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

    self.popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
}, completion: { _ in
     self.popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)
})
```

For Zoom Out

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It doesnt work as i want. This code just pops up and goes.

Comment: Hi Kaushik Below code worked for me. Thanks for you help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for Pop Out

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.popupView.alpha = 0.0;
            self.popupInnerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.popupView.isHidden = true
            self.popupInnerView.isHidden = true
        })
```